# MongoDB unauthorized users can create databases

Tags: mongodb

We have an old **MongoDb 2.2.6** deployment and lately we were requested to introduce anonymous user blocking to the Db. I followed the MongoDb tutorials and created an authentication user first and started the mongod with

> --auth

parameter.

Then after login, I could not execute any db related commands except for the

> use << db >>

. Everything was perfect. But then I tried issuing

> use <<< some_junk_db_name >>

without authentication and then issued

> db.some_collection.find()

command. Mongodb correctly raised an exception but later when I checked, that DB was there.

Is this a bug with MongoDb 2.2.6 or am I missing something here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [reported Bug with the number 2080](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2080) and the ticket is still not fixed. The last comment, May 17 2013, from a MongoDB Inc. member says that the Bug is still existing in the 2.4 version of MongoDB.

In Version 3.4 the Bug was no longer reproducable.

Comment: Note that this creates a phantom (empty) database rather than allocating storage for the DB (but is still a bug). The database name should not persist after a restart of `mongod`.